# What does OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED_3_0 mean?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

For example, consider this snippet:

```
# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED_3_0
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 size_t HMAC_size(const HMAC_CTX *e);
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 HMAC_CTX *HMAC_CTX_new(void);
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 int HMAC_CTX_reset(HMAC_CTX *ctx);
OSSL_DEPRECATEDIN_3_0 void HMAC_CTX_free(HMAC_CTX *ctx);
# endif
```

I want to understand what exactly OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED_3_0 means, the wordplay is confusing to me, is it not deprecated or is it deprecated?

Comment: All of those functions are deprecated in 3.0 (use the EVP_MAC API for HMAC)

Comment: Then from openssl/hmac.h only one function is not deprecated in 3.0 - https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/openssl/openssl/-/blob/include/openssl/hmac.h?L54 - is my understanding right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the OpenSSL page:

> `OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED` —  If this macro is defined, all deprecated public
> symbols in all OpenSSL versions up to and including the version given
> by `OPENSSL_API_COMPAT` (or the default value given above, when
> `OPENSSL_API_COMPAT` isn't defined) will be hidden.

Comment: OpenSSL compile config uses many macros of the form `OPENSSL_NO_{XXX}` all of which mean "omit/exclude/don't compile {XXX}" so `_NO_MD2` means omit MD2, `_NO_SSL3` means omit SSL3, etc., and `_NO_DEPRECATED` means omit the deprecated routines (or here declarations for them).